# Sorting in XSLT, only when string-length != 0

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I use the following block of XSLT to get the description from the 'newest' item out of an XML file. It sorts by date (which is displayed like in my XML as `<date>2011-11-15</date>`), and then picks the top one from the sorted list. Though I just discovered that some items don't have a date, and they're simply displayed like `<date/>`. The problem is that my XSLT sorts these at the top of my sorted list, and thus picking items without a date first.

So, how do I sort items by date, which have a length higher than zero?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/products/product">
      <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring(date,0,4))" order="ascending" />
      <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring(date,4,2))" order="ascending" />
      <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring(date,7,2))" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
      <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just want to leave them out. It's an XML generated by Magento, so I can't remove the entry by hand. It's just there, so the only way to get it "out of my code" is to simply ignore those entries.

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid including the ones without a date in the sort:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/products/product[date]">
```

Incidentally (a) you seem to be picking the earliest item in the list, not the latest, and (b) there's really no need to split the date into three parts for formatting: if all the dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD then a straight alphabetic sort should do the job, unless the system decides to use an odd collating sequence, in which case `<xsl:sort select="number(translate(date, '-', ''))" data-type="number"/>` might be safer.

Comment: Actually the date is displayed like `<date>2012-01-23 00:00:00</date>` so I can't get your code to work.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal, Please, edit the question and provide a source XML document (small) instance -- people shouldn't have to guess what the data is.